# PHP error with using strings as an array

Tags: php, curl

I get a website as a cURL response, and I pass it to this function. Then I itterate through the string, doing some processing. It works, but I get this error:

> Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 75817 in
>   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/crg-daily/lib/CragslistRawDumpProcessor.class.php
>   on line 7

Here is the code:

```
public function rollSausage($dump){
    $anchorArray = array();
    $dumpLength = strlen($dump);
    $skipToLetter = 1;
    while($skipToLetter < $dumpLength){
        $skipToLetter++;
        $letter = $dump[$skipToLetter];
        ...
    }
}
```

Any ideas? I think it has something to do with the type of string being submitted. It is a raw cUrl response. I'm scraping a web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increment your `$skipToLetter` after you use it (preferably at the end of the while loop). And you might also start at 0, not 1

```
 $skipToLetter = 0;
 while($skipToLetter < $dumpLength){
            $letter = $dump[$skipToLetter];
    ...
            $skipToLetter++;
            }
        }
```

Here's the reason: assume you have a string with length of 4. This means that the last index in the string is `3`. Your index goes up to 3. It gets compared in the while loop `(3<4)?` and the answer is `true`. The code enters the while loop and increments the value of the index which will be greater than the last index of the string, thus causing the warning.

Answer (score 1):

Updated your code...

```
public function rollSausage($dump){
    $anchorArray = array();
    $dumpLength = strlen($dump);
    $skipToLetter = 1;
    while($skipToLetter < $dumpLength){
        $skipToLetter++;
         if( siset( $dump[$skipToLetter]) )
            $letter = $dump[$skipToLetter];
...
        }
    }
```

}